# JGroups with JBoss application server

Tags: jboss, jgroups

Where can I find a basic example of code for using Jgroups with JBoss application server.
Jboss application server (version 7 or 6) ships with JGroups (used for custering). 
I simply want to reuse this jgroups module in order to do server to server messaging.

Answer (score 1):

[1] provides a good starting point.

[1] http://piotrnowicki.com/2013/02/using-jgroups-directly-from-jboss-as-7-component/